# How can I get my root domain to stop supporting TLS 1.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, tls1.2, amazon-route53

When I SSL scan my root domain (example.com) it supports TLS 1.0. However, when I scan [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), I do not see TLS 1.0 support. My route53 records are pointing to the same load balancer. How is this possible?

Comment: Can you post more details about your setup?

Comment: As far as I can tell, we currently have Route 53 directing to the google name servers  as described here:
 https://support.google.com/a/answer/2579934?hl=en
We have a load balancer, which the www.example.com record points to via CNAME. when I used an alias to point the apex domain to that Load Balancer, it seemed to fail in testing.